# If the source code of SHA256 hashing algorithm is available in public, why can't it be hacked?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, sha-256

If the SHA256 algorithm is public, why can't attackers use it to create more collisions rendering the algorithm useless?

Comment: Because it is one-way function.

Comment: Finding collisions doesn't make a hash function "useless" either, it depends what it is used for. It may still create well distributed output and may be invulnerable against pre-image attacks. The generation of collisions also has per-conditions attached to them. Of course, we'd still favor unbroken hash functions, which is why everybody steers away from MD5 and SHA-1.

Comment: There simply is no reason that being public implies being weak. Thus indeed the question boils down to: _What makes SHA-256 secure?_